# Passing boolean operation to a function

Tags: java, boolean-expression

Good evening guys,
just as the titel says, my intention is, to pass a boolean operation like `!x&&z`
to a function so that I can apply this operation later on. The plan will be to transfer any boolean operation into a truth table. All what I need is a bit of recursion for the different inputs, a string analysis to convert String to boolean in the end applying this boolean operation to the recursion.
Beside the string analysis I just want to try to apply a boolean operation to the recursion. Is there any way to do that easily?

As wanted I will include a bit of code:

```
 private static String recursivAequi(boolean[] bools,int id,BoolOp op,BoolOp op2)
{
    String values[]=new String[]{"true","false"};
    for(String i:values)
    {
        bools[bools.length-id-1]=Boolean.valueOf(i);
        if(id!=0)
        {
            return recursivAequi(bools,id-1,op,op2);
        }
        else
        {
            boolean one=op.TruthValue(bools);
            boolean two =op2.TruthValue(bools);
            if(one^two)
            {
                return false+"";
            }
        }
    }
    return true+"";
}
```

so this methode will check, if two boolean operations are a equivalent to each other by inserting true and false for every variable the boolean expression has.
My Interface BoolOP looks now like this:
`public interface BoolOp {
    public boolean TruthValue(boolean[] bools);
}`

I want to test this via a System out. My problem now is, how to pass a boolean array into a lambda expresssion.
I did this:

```
System.out.println(recursivAequi(new boolean[2],1,boolarray->boolarray[0]&&boolarray[1],boolarray->boolarray[1]&&boolarray[0]);
```

So the first array is just a placeholder in which the true and false values of my recursive function will be put in. the id is neccessary to have a break within the recursive function and the two following lambdas are the two boolean expressions I want to test.

Hope this helped a bit to understand the problem.

Comment: So, you want to pass a function that takes two values as inputs, and returns a boolean, is that right? Look into BiPredicate. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiPredicate.html. If not, then clarify, with an example.

Comment: Context and code would help this question greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you could create an interface for the Boolean Operation objects and whenever you want to add one, utilize [Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

```
public interface BoolOp {
    public boolean TruthValue(boolean x, boolean z);
}
...
public void performBoolOp (BoolOp op) {
    op.TruthValue(true, true);
}
...
performBoolOp((x, z) -> !x^z);
```

As you pass a reference of the object as an instance of the BoolOp interface, it must have implemented the TruthValue function, hence you may invoke it as such.

**Note:**

`(x, z) -> !x^z` is essentially the same, just more concise, as:

`new BoolOp() {
     @Override
     public boolean TruthValue(boolean x, boolean y) {
         return !x^z;
     }
 };`